# How can I load a long list and stay/start on the bottom of the view without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

We have a message view in our app where we on initial rendering load a list of messages which are then rendered, going from `<div>Loading ....</div>` to `[<Message>,<Message>,...,<InputBox>]` (pseudo-jsx). Upon loading, the view is extended to many times the screen length, so we need to scroll to the bottom `onLoad()`. This is bothersome :

- lazy loading images in the older parts of the conversation won't work, as we "scroll past" them, triggering loading
- there should be no need to do `scrollTo(99999)`: we want to start a freshly loaded page on the bottom!

So how can I have the initial "scroll position" of a container be the bottom of the container? This seems like a quite basic thing.

Comment: Have you tried using a configurable infinite scroll component? Lots of them around

Comment: Just load the last # to fill the `VH - y` to accomodate scrolling up a half screen or so. You will still have to `scrollTo`, but the loading burden will be lessoned. Then, upon scrolling up, dynamically load one screen's worth at a time.  (By the way, there are a lot of things that are bothersome in what we do :-) )

Comment: This: "_freshly loaded page on the bottom!_" - the issue has to do with how browsers parse the HTML. They parse all files from top to bottom and build the DOM and CSSOM in the order the elements are found (with some optimization going on). Due to this, the rendering and then painting of the GUI is from top to bottom preserving the view from top to bottom too. So `scrollTo()` will be your friend like it or not.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I was wondering if it perhaps was possible to somehow render the long list component out of view and set the "container internal" scroll position before showing it. The point about dynamically loading previous elements is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following contrived example is designed to show you one possible solution by emulating your scenario. If I have this wrong please correct me.

(React example linked at bottom)

Ten images are loaded into individual `<div>` elements. To emulate network/loading delay each `<div><img></div>` is loaded every 1/2 second. Notice that nothing is visible while this happens other than the "Loading..." placeholder. Five seconds later, after all are loaded, a custom event is fired to indicate the loading is complete. The very last image will be dark blue rather than the light blue of the others.

An event handler responds to the custom event by removing the "Loading..." indicator, scrolling to the bottom `<div>` and finally setting visibility of the entire section to `visible`.

Note the `<div>`s just *appear* and the `<section>` has been scrolled to the bottom. The bottom `<div>` is the dark blue one.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('section');
const divsToAdd = 10
let divCounter = 0;
const interval = setInterval(addDiv, 500);

document.addEventListener('panelLoadComplete', () => {
  document.querySelector('section span:first-child').remove();
  document.querySelector('section div:last-child').scrollIntoView();
  container.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

function addDiv() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  div.style.display = 'inherit';
  div.appendChild(img);
  container.appendChild(div);
  if (divCounter === divsToAdd) { // is last - dark blue
    img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000ff"
  } else {
    img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/100/0088ff"
  }
  if (++divCounter > divsToAdd) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('panelLoadComplete'));
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  visibility: hidden;
}

section span:first-child {
  visibility: visible;
}

section>div:first-child {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

section>div:last-child {
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span>Loading... (patience: this takes ~5 seconds)</span>
</section>
```

Finally, a simple React version:

[React Example StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chroce?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: This is exactly how I imagined I would do it. Great stuff. AFAIK you need to set the section to hidden, as opposed to display:none, to actually force the browser to render the dom nodes, right? Thus getting an actual height on the elements, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The difference between `display='none'` and `visibility='hidden'`: Display property does not put the elements into the _rendered_ DOM _until_ `display` is set, whereas `visibility` renders the elements into the DOM but does not _show_ them until `visibility` is set.